# Difference between typedef struct and struct?

Tags: c, struct

I know the basic difference between them just have a doubt in particular situation 
like following:

```
struct books{
    int id;
    char* title;    
  }book;

book.id=9;    // this is valid;
```

But in case of `typedef` :

```
typedef struct books{
  int id;
  char*title;
}book;
book.id=9;    //it is not valid we have to do like book b1; then b1.id=9 is valid
```

What is going on here can u tell me?

Comment: Well, the first example defined a variable `book` of type `struct books`. The second defines a type alias `book` to the type `struct books`, but no variable. Saying `book.id = 9` here is like saying `float = 1.2f`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first case, you are creating an object of type `struct books` named `book`.

In the second, you are defining an alias `book` for the type `struct books`. Thus `book` is not an object but a type name.